# on what Sql Server product levels the Change Data Capture (CDC) feature is available?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, change-data-capture

I have a project, which involves using Sql Server 2012 Standard Edition.
This project needs to have Sql Server Change Data Capture enabled (CDC).
Is CDC available in Sql Server Standard Edition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try to enable it on standard, you should get an error message along these lines:

> Change data capture is only available in the Enterprise, Developer,
>   and Enterprise Evaluation editions

And here is a more definitive link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

CDC is available only in Enterprise Edition, but you can use Change Tracking in Standard edition:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.110).aspx

You can check your requirements in such a way that you can accomplish only using CT